TestNG xml with suite level group tag and listener tag not working
I am facing issue with running TestNG XML by adding groups tag at suite level with Listener.
if group tag is added at suite level without listener tag it works.
if listener tag is added without suite level group tag it works.
if group tag is added and below listener tag is added then group works but listener fails.
if listener tag is added below suite and then group tag is added below listener then group doesn't work.
Expecting to make both tags work at suite level

Please edit your question and include a sample that can show us what your suite file looks like. Please also include the version of TestNG that you are working with
